# Can't pass a variable through my view to the html template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

So I'm trying to: pass a variable `owner_id` in the view `def new(request, owner_id)` to render `new.html` that it will be used in the action of a form as a parameter/argument `action="{{ url 'new' owner_id }}"`.

Like This:

```
def new(request, owner_id):  # from here
if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
else:
    category = Category.objects.all()
    render(request, "auctions/new.html", {
        "category": category,
        "owner_id": owner_id  # <--- to HERE
    })
```

[view.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZEbk.png)

[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj5CZ.png)

[new.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqZEB.png)  **Error** detected in this file by django

[Layout.html template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiZnT.png)

> *Could not parse the remainder*

[ERROR screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbtKb.png)

It's driving me crazy... I can't understand why its not working.

And the worst part is I already did it on another view and it WORKED!
The only difference is here I use the same variable again inside in the form to "**feed**" it again, throught the same url, view... etc.
Whether there (another url and view) I used it as a normal variable inside the brakets {{ }}.

PD: I probably lack the basic understanding how django starts to process all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *template tag* is written between `{%` and `%}`, not `{{ url 'new' owner_id }}`, so:

```
action="{% url 'new' owner_id %}"
```

Comment: you are such a hero... That was it... now it asks me about not passing an HttpResponse
(The view auctions.views.new didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.) But that is a different story I think... Thank you very much!